# Why does ArrayList not throw ConcurrentModificationException when modified from multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, thread-safety

ConcurrentModificationException : This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent modification of an object when such modification is not permissible.

Above is ConcurrentModificationException definition from javadoc.

So I try to test below code:

```
final List<String> tickets = new ArrayList<String>(100000);
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    tickets.add("ticket NO," + i);
}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Thread salethread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (tickets.size() > 0) {
                tickets.remove(0);
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId()+"Remove 0");
            }
        }
    };
    salethread.start();
}
```

The code is simple.
10 threads remove the element from the arraylist object.
It is sure that multiple threads access one object. But it runs OK. No exception is thrown.
Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm quoting a large section of the [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) Javadoc for your benefit. Relevant portions that explain the behavior you are seeing are highlighted.

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads
>   access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the
>   threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized
>   externally**. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or
>   deletes one or more elements, or explicitly resizes the backing array;
>   merely setting the value of an element is not a structural
>   modification.) This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some
>   object that naturally encapsulates the list. If no such object exists,
>   the list should be "wrapped" using the Collections.synchronizedList
>   method. This is best done at creation time, to prevent accidental
>   unsynchronized access to the list:
>
> List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(...));
>
> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods
>   are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after
>   the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own
>   remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a
>   ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent
>   modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than
>   risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time
>   in the future.
>
> **Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed
>   as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees
>   in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification**. Fail-fast
>   iterators throw ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort
>   basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended
>   on this exception for its correctness: the fail-fast behavior of
>   iterators should be used only to detect bugs.

ArrayLists will generally throw concurrent modification exceptions if you modify the list structurally ***while accessing it through its iterator*** (but even this is not an absolute guarantee). Note that in your example you are removing elements from the list directly, and you are not using an iterator.

If it tickles your fancy, you can also browse the implementation of [`ArrayList.remove`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.remove%28int%29), to get a better understanding of how it works.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think 'concurrent' means thread-related in this case, or at least it doesn't necessarily mean that. `ConcurrentModificationException`s usually arise from modifying a collection while in the process of iterating over it.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String s : list)
{
     //modifying list results in ConcurrentModificationException
     list.add("don't do this");     

}
```

Note that the `Iterator<>` class has a few methods that can circumvent this:

```
for(Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext())
{
     //no ConcurrentModificationException
     it.remove(); 
}
```

Comment: +1 Short and simple.  Concurrent does not necessarily mean parallel (as your answer illustrates).

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are not receiving a `ConcurrentModificationException` is that `ArrayList.remove` does not throw one. You can probably get one by starting an additional thread that iterates through the array:

```
final List<String> tickets = new ArrayList<String>(100000);
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    tickets.add("ticket NO," + i);
}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Thread salethread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (tickets.size() > 0) {
                tickets.remove(0);
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId()+"Remove 0");
            }
        }
    };
    salethread.start();
}
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        int totalLength = 0;
        for (String s : tickets) {
            totalLength += s.length();
        }
    }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not using an iterator, there is no chance of a `ConcurrentModificationException` being thrown.

Calling `remove(0)` will simply remove the first element. It might not be the *same* element intended by the caller if another thread removes 0 before execution completes.

Answer (score 1):

> But it runs OK. No exception is thrown. Why?

Simply because that concurrent modification is permissible.

The description of the exception says this:

> *"This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent modification of an object **when such modification is not permissible.**"*

The clear implication is that are (or may be) *permissible* concurrent modifications.  And in fact for the standard Java non-concurrent collection classes, concurrent modifications are permitted ... provided that they don't happen during an iteration.

---

The reasoning behind this is that for the non-concurrent collections, modification while iterating is fundamentally unsafe and unpredictable.  Even if you were to synchronize correctly (and that isn't easy<sup>1</sup>), the result would still be unpredictable.  The "fail-fast" checks for concurrent modifications were included in the regular collection classes because this was a common source of Heisenbugs in multi-threaded applications that used the Java 1.1 collection classes.

<sup>1- For instance, the "synchronizedXxx" wrapper classes don't, and can't synchronize with iterators.  The problem is that iteration involves alternating calls to `next()` and `hasNext()`, and the only way to do a pair of method calls while excluding other threads is to use external synchronization.  The wrapper approach isn't practical in Java.</sup>